# No connection string named 'ATX_PLSNGEntities' could be found in the application config file although it is include

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have two projects:

The first one (VTB_Terminliste) was build as a class library (.dll) with Entity Framework. [image: first project]

The second one is the main application, which include VTB_Terminliste as .dll, which I want to show after click button, like:

```
Private Sub btnTerminliste_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTerminliste.Click
   Dim l As New VTB_Terminliste.MainView
   l.Show()
End Sub
```

[image: secondProject]

In my App.Config from main application I insert the connection string for my Entites

```
<add name="ATX_PLSNGEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBA_Terminliste.csdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.ssdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=atx-srv-58;initial catalog=ATX_PLSNG;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomePW;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

After start and click the button `btnTerminliste` I get an error "No connection string named 'ATX_PLSNGEntities' could be found in the application config file"

If I start VTB_Terminliste project as WinForm every thing is working.

Here are my App.Config from project VTB_Terminliste and the main application

VTB_Terminliste

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System">
      <section name="DevExpress.LookAndFeel.Design.AppSettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <DevExpress.LookAndFeel.Design.AppSettings>
      <setting name="DefaultAppSkin" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Skin/The Bezier</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultPalette" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Gloom Gloom</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="TouchUI" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="TouchScaleFactor" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DirectX" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="RegisterUserSkins" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FontBehavior" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultAppFont" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DPIAwarenessMode" serializeAs="String">
        <value>System</value>
      </setting>
    </DevExpress.LookAndFeel.Design.AppSettings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <!-- Dieser Abschnitt definiert die Protokollierungskonfiguration für My.Application.Log -->
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="FileLog" />
          <!-- Auskommentierung des nachfolgenden Abschnitts aufheben, um in das Anwendungsereignisprotokoll zu schreiben -->
          <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter" />
      <!-- Auskommentierung des nachfolgenden Abschnitts aufheben und APPLICATION_NAME durch den Namen der Anwendung ersetzen, um in das Anwendungsereignisprotokoll zu schreiben -->
      <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ATX_PLSNGEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBA_Terminliste.csdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.ssdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=atx-srv-58;initial catalog=ATX_PLSNG;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomePW;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Main application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ATX_DBA_Test_Connection" connectionString="XpoProvider=MSSqlServer;data source=atx-srv-28;user id=sa;password=Zu3545Uz;initial catalog=ATX_DBA_Test;Persist Security Info=true" />
        <add name="ATX_PLSNGEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBA_Terminliste.csdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.ssdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=atx-srv-58;initial catalog=ATX_PLSNG;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomePW;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I hope someone can help find me a solution.

Comment: Read the error message and then tell us where exactly the connection string with that name is.

Comment: @jmcilhinney this is my error message 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'No connection string named 'ATX_PLSNGEntities' could be found in the application config file.'' and the connection string is in app.config in main application(VTB_Auftragsverwaltung) and VTB_Terminliste

Comment: Then why does the title of your thread say differently?  If you're going to post false information then you're not going to encourage others to help.

Comment: Different?! Only the word in ' ' is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem adding the connection string inside `.Context.vb`

```
Partial Public Class ATX_PLSNGEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
      MyBase.New("metadata=res://*/DBA_Terminliste.csdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.ssdl|res://*/DBA_Terminliste.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=SomeServer;initial catalog=ATX_PLSNG;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomePW;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
      Throw New UnintentionalCodeFirstException()
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Property Terminliste() As DbSet(Of Terminliste)

  End Class
```